# subsetting data frame with selected factors

Tags: r

After dabbling around for a some time now my mind is a bit scattered about a procedure of sub setting a data frame, `wnd`, which has a variable column `ORIGIN` (class:factor).

```
a = sort(table(wnd$ORIGIN), decreasing=T)[1:20]
a

ATL    ORD    DFW    DEN    LAX    IAH    PHX    SFO    CLT..
123915  94422  90184  70970  69298  58850  57316  52702  44234..
```

`# a is a table 20 factors of interest (highest volume).`

```
b = names(a) 
b
[1] "ATL" "ORD" "DFW" "DEN" "LAX" "IAH" "PHX" "SFO" "CLT" "LAS" "DTW" "EWR" "MSP"
[14] "MCO" "SLC" "JFK" "BOS" "BWI" "LGA" "SEA"
#b pulls out the names of the airport i require in my subset
```

Then I would like to create a new data frame with only these factors in `b` in it(i.e. subsetting).  For one they are not of same class:

```
> class(b)
[1] "character"

> class(wnd$ORIGIN)
[1] "factor
```

I tried few different things(`as.factor(b)`, `wnd$ORIGIN==b`, etc)  but now my confusion is growing and could like someone to explain what is the correct way(s) of thinking about this.

Comment: try `wnd[wnd$ORIGIN %in% b, ]`, with `==` you do elementwise comparison across vectors, try `1:3 == 2:4`

Comment: `factor(b)` may be what you need

Comment: Thanks.  %n% seem to work.  ( sum(a) was 1055254) and  dim(wnd[wnd$ORIGIN %in% (b),])
[1] 1055254     110

Answer (score 2):

`data.frame` turns character strings into factors by default.

```
data.frame(origin=b, count=unname(a))
  origin count
1    DFW     8
2    ATL     6
3    ORD     3
```

`unname` removes the name attribute from `a` because of the output of `table`.

**Data**

```
set.seed(111)
a <- c("ATL", "ORD", "DFW", "DEN", "LAX")
wnd <- data.frame(ORIGIN=sample(x,20,T))
a <- sort(table(wnd$ORIGIN), decreasing=T)[1:3]
b <- names(a)
```

Comment: %in% worked for mixing and matching with vector b.  I need some time to wrap my head around your post.  Thks

Comment: You don't even need `factor` come to think about it. There is a `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` default in R when creating data.frames, so nothing really has to be done to `b`.